# Android Nougat notification action button not showing in notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-7.0-nougat

Here is the library used in app level build.gradle file:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Here is the code for notification :

```
 Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        snoozeIntent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID", 0);
        PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),"Hello")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .setContentTitle("My Custom Notification")
                .setContentText("Hello Custom")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_battery_charging_full_white_24dp)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add,"Action 1",snoozePendingIntent);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build());
```